# How to version control dynamically created tables and views

Tags: tfs, ssis

My team supports ETLs (SSIS packages) which dynamically create tables and views on a monthly and weekly basis (i.e. tbl_fact_cust_yyyymm and vw_fact_cust_yyyymm).

Is there a way to automatically capture these additional tables and views that get created by the ETLs and check them into TFS version control so TFS stays in sync with the production database?

Comment: Why do you need a version control of dynamically created objects? All you need in TFS is the dynamic code.

Comment: Can you please explain more how you do an incremental update of production DB (except the changes made by SSIS). I'm just wondering if you use DACPAC or incremental scripts. One more important question whether you support backward compatibility or not

Comment: BI Dude - If changes are required to historical tables and views, we'd like to roll the change out to all objects and have TFS build produce the change script for us.

Comment: Vladimir Semashkin - Currently developers use SQL Compare to generate an incremental SQL script (difference between dev and prod), which is provided to a DBA to run. We do support backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way on TFS side to check in dynamically files automatically. You could code your requirement using tf commands:

[Add command:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-command)

```
tf add itemspec [/lock:(none|checkin|checkout)] [/encoding:filetype] 
[/noprompt] [/recursive] [/noignore] [/login:username,[password]]
```

[Checkin command:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/checkin-command)

```
tf checkin [/author:author name] [/comment:("comment"|@comment file)] 
[/noprompt] [/notes:("Note Name"="note text"|@notefile)] 
[/override:(reason|@reasonfile)] [/recursive] [/saved] [/validate] [itemspec] [/bypass] [/force] [/noautoresolve]  [/login:username,[password]] [/new]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Cece. Is there a convenient way to find the differences between a database and what's currently in TFS using a tf command? Or would that be something we'd have to code up additionally?

Comment: Are you looking for [Difference Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/difference-command)?

Comment: I voted for your answer, but my vote doesn't count yet since I'm a new user.